# Cron expression failing after upgrading from v1.6.0 to v2.3.2

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I was upgrading version to some old/deprecated libraries I'm using on my projects and after solving failed tests, compilation erros, etc; I came across this one that cannot solve yet.

There's a unit tests which verifies a cron expression is valid. Thing is that this has been working for years: method `CronExpression.isValidExpression(cronExpression)` was returning `true` for expression **0 0/1 * * * *** in v1.6.0 but after upgrading it to v2.3.2, is now failing with following message: **Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.**

Question is: from one version to another cron expressions are no longer valid? How can I convert this former valid  expression to a current valid one?

Comment: Can you use either the day-of-week OR the day-of-month parameter (but not both at the same time)?

Comment: But is there a reason on why it wasn't failing before? Looks like expressions became more strict.

Comment: You could try digging through their github (or whatever they're using), but at a guess, it was probably "valid" but not actually working (i.e. leading to weird behaviours), so they explicitly blocked it.  In other words, I'm guessing it was a gap in their validation logic.

Comment: @Clawdidr Have you asked the original author of the library why the expression worked in a previous version and why it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @Progman, actually no. I was hoping he would read me question and jump in :)